# CentOS 6.4 does not seem to have patches for OpenSSL

Tags: centos, openssl

Just wondering if anyone knows why CentOS hasn't released an update to OpenSSL? I have a 6.4 machine and updated openSSL but when I issue the "openssl version -a" it's showing 1.0.1e-30. However, if you run "rpm -q openssl | grep CVE-2015" or CVE-2014 it does not show the latest things that were discovered on the OpenSSL website like CVE-2015-0206 or CVE-2014-3571 (and there are many others).

Why has CentOS not issued a patched version for these things in OpenSSL in this case?

This is not looking for Heartbleed, but the latest issues with OpenSSL that have come out as of 01/08/2015 which are not in the changelog of CentOS's OpenSSL

Comment: You did not "update the whole box". If you did, you would not be on 6.4.

Comment: 6.6 uses the same version. I keep that kernel because there is a dependency that I have to have 6.4 for.

Comment: `rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep CVE-2014-0160`
`- fix CVE-2014-0160 - information disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension`

Comment: that's a different CVE number. 0160 has nothing to do with the ones I'm interested in. If you go to [link](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html) you can see the numbers there. None of which are contained in the changelog of OpenSSL. 
CVE-2014-3571, CVE-2015-0206,CVE-2015-0205, etc, etc

Comment: Not sure why you guys have downvoted this question. All the information is there and running those commands does not show any updates to OpenSSL for any 2015 CVE numbers. You just responded saying I didn't update it to 6.6 (even though it has the same version of OpenSSL) and then sent a CVE number for 0160 which was never in the question...

Comment: Though the need for a "6.4" Kernel is pretty dubious, the downvoting over not understanding how to follow the CVE -> RHSA -> errata bread crumbs is a little harsh even for this site. It's really not the most intuitive process if you don't have someone to explain it.

Comment: @AaronCopley The original post, which was much worse, and seemed to be a duplicate, is probably where the downvotes came from.  Until SE builds in a way to notify voters of changes to posts they've voted on, there's going to be an issue with improved posts' scores reflecting their original state rather than their improved one.

Comment: Fair enough. (I just read the original.) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS will only ship what Red Hat ships. So, use [Red Hat's CVE search](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/) when you question errata availability;

> Statement
>
> This issue **does not affect** the version of openssl and openssl097a as
>   shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. This issue **does not affect**
>   the version of openssl098e as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
>   and 7.

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2015-0205

> This issue **does not affect** the version of openssl and openssl097a as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. This issue **does not affect** the version of openssl098e as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and 7.

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2015-0206

> Statement
>
> This issue **does not affect** the version of openssl097a as shipped with
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. This issue **affects** the version of
>   openssl098e as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and 7.

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-3571

---

When warrented, Red Hat will issue a Red Hat Service Advisory, RHSA, which will lead you to the released errata for the CVE.

Ex:

[CVE-2014-0160](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-0160) -> [RHSA-2014:0376](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0376.html) -> [Errata](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0376.html#Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%20Server%20%28v.%206%29)

Comment: so the answer is that 'it affects' 0.9.8 and above (as is the case for CVE-2014-3571) but they have chosen not to fix it? ouch.

Comment: Beats me. I'm a little puzzled by that, too. But, that's your explanation for why CentOS hasn't released anything. Now, if you were a paying subscriber to Red Hat you could ask your TAM what's up. :)

Comment: Nevermind, I overlooked it. There's an open Bugzilla entry for it. It's in progress. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2014-3571

Comment: Ugh, I still read it wrong; This issue affects the version of openssl098e as shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and 7. Red Hat Product Security has rated this issue as having Moderate security impact **and does not plan to address this flaw for the above components in any future security updates.**

Comment: Also, to add to the confusion (per the conversation at Bugzilla), [this came out today](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0066.html) which claims to address CVE-2014-3571?